# i am having issue using query function of google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, xlsx, google-query-language

I am trying to query an XLSX file with the following statement =query($A$2:$E$34, "select E WHERE C = '1' AND A = 'Jun-21'"), in that case, C being a country number and A being the month and year and I am not able to get a value, I receive N/A saying that it has been completed with an empty result, even though there is a number matching criteria on the dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A2:E34), "select Col5 where Col3 = '1' and Col1 = 'Jun-21'"))
```